# Write a query to display the name of the player who has been declared as 'player of match' for maximum number of times

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Two tables- Player,Outcome

In player table - id int(11),name varchar(50)

in outcome table - id int(11);

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Another way (if you only want the name):

```
SELECT name
FROM player
WHERE id IN (
  SELECT TOP 1 player_of_match
  FROM outcome
  GROUP BY player_of_match
  ORDER BY count(player_of_match) DESC
)
```

or alternatively:

```
SELECT TOP 1 b.name
FROM outcome a, player b
WHERE a.player_of_match = b.id
GROUP BY b.name
ORDER BY count(player_of_match) DESC
```

Honzy's answer is also valid, though you have to include `p.name` in your `GROUP BY` clause as it's not an aggregate field.

**EDIT** Apologies - above queries are SQL Server, just realised you tagged MySql, I don't think you can use the TOP 1 syntax - replace that with a LIMIT 1 at the end.

Also poster has asked to list all names of players if there is a tie - in that case you may need to do something along these lines:

```
SELECT name 
FROM player
WHERE id IN (
  SELECT player_of_match FROM outcome
  GROUP BY player_of_match
  HAVING COUNT(player_of_match) = (
    SELECT TOP 1 COUNT(player_of_match) from outcome
    GROUP BY player_of_match
    ORDER BY COUNT(player_of_match) DESC
  )
)
```

I'm sure there's probably a more elegant way of doing this, but it gets the job done (this is SQL Server notation again, in MySql TOP will again probably have to be replaced with LIMIT notation).

Comment: Cool - any reason you can see why someone has voted down all the answers?! Seems a little mean, as far as I can see, they're all valid :-)

Comment: One correction is here... For example, consider 5 times is the maximum number of times player_of_match occurs at the same time if 3 players got 5 times player of match then it should display 3 players name not  1 player  name

Comment: OK - probably need to specify that in question a little more - you can test against the max number in the having clause - I'll edit my answer to show it. I use SQL Server rather than MySql so again you'll probably have to replace TOP notation with LIMIT.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT p.id, p.name, COUNT(o.id) `number_of_times` FROM player p
LEFT JOIN outcome o ON (p.id = o.player_of_match)
GROUP BY p.id
ORDER BY COUNT(o.id) DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* it addresses the question.  Without that, your answer has much less educational value - remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT p.name 
FROM outcome o 
LEFT JOIN player p on p.id=player_of_match 
GROUP BY player_of_match 
ORDER BY COUNT(player_of_match) DESC 
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* it addresses the question.  Without that, your answer has much less educational value - remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.